# Item gets deleted on flush even when I restore it

Tags: symfony, flush, symfony-2.8

I have the following code that I'm using to debug:

```
$localResource = $xResource->getLocalResource();
dump($localResource->getAllOptions()->toArray());

$xProvider->updateLocalResource($xResource, $localResource, $handler);
dump($localResource->getAllOptions()->toArray());

if ($flush) {
    $this->em->flush();
}
dump($localResource->getAllOptions()->toArray());
die;
```

The first `dump` shows the local resource, which in this case is currently deleted, so `deletedAt` is a timestamp.

The second `dump` shows the local resource, after it has been restored. `deletedAt` at this stage is `null`.

The third `dump` shows the local resource, after it is flushed. `deletedAt` is then the current timestamp when the code runs. This timestamp is not the same as the timestamp in the first `dump`.

I thought it might be cascading deleting somewhere, but seems it's not. I've checked events too, with no luck.

Here is the code where I do the restore:

```
$extra = $extrasRepo->findOneBy(['externalId' => $id, 'boat' => $localResource->getId()]);

if (empty($extra)) {
    $extra = new BoatExtra();
    $extra->setExternalId($id);
} else {
    $extra->restore();
    $extra->getAsset()->restore();
}
```

Is there anything else that I'm missing? Why would it - with a flush call - redelete the item.